# How much fuel gets dumped and why?

Tags: fuel, fuel-dumping

WRT [Would the Aeroflot Flight 1492 have been able to dump its fuel first before landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/64212), I am wondering how much fuel gets dumped every year? gallons? litres? pounds?

Also, is it only in unplanned or emergency situations?

Comment: Why would anyone _plan_ to dump fuel?

Comment: Most shorthaul aircraft do not have the capability to dump fuel.

Comment: Only in emergencies.  It'll be a pretty small number.  You might find something like a study on the IATA web site.  It doesn't effect people on the ground because the fuel evaporates pretty quickly.

Comment: It's better to submit the update as an answer, see here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Related: [How often does fuel dumping from planes in flight actually occur?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8864/14897)

Answer (score 2):

While according to British Airways estimates quoted in the Inter-Governmental Panel on Climate Change (IPPC) report on “Aviation and the Global Atmosphere” published in 1999 “only a very small percentage (on the order of 0.01%) of fuel used by the aviation industry each year is jettisoned”

https://greentumble.com/environmental-impacts-of-fuel-dumping/